# Is it possible to use a Mutator within a Mutator in C++?

Tags: c++, validation, setter

Good afternoon!

I did some quick searching around and I was having a hard time trying to figure out how I should go about doing what I need to do.

For this program, we are creating a basic work ticket class. Each attribute has its own mutator and accessor, but in addition there will be a mutator that takes all the attributes as parameters and set them all in one go.

The main reason I can't just use the constructor to place in the values, is because for this mutator we have to perform some validation on the values. For the individual attribute mutators, two of them already have the validation performed in their mutator. The other two only have to be validated when the setWorkTicket mutator is called.

Is there a way to call a mutator from within a mutator? Or would the only way to make sure it validates the two attributes be to copy and paste their validation from their mutators into the setWorkTicket?

If you need clarification, or what I'm asking is unclear just let me know. I have attached the class in question.

```
/** Lab2.cpp
 *  @desc       SOME DESCRIPTION
 *  @author     Aaron, Aaron
 *  @since      24 September 2014
 **/


#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include "MyInputValidation.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

class WorkTicket
{
    public:
        /*** PARAMETERIZED CONSTRUCTOR ***/
        WorkTicket(): myWorkTicketNumber(0), myClientID(""), myDay(1), myMonth(1), myYear(2000), myIssue("") {}

        WorkTicket(int workTicketNumber, string clientID, int day, int month, int year, string issue);

        /*** ACCESSORS ***/
        int getWorkTicketNumber() const { return myWorkTicketNumber; }

        string getClientID() const { return myClientID; }

        string getDate(int myDay, int myMonth, int myYear) const;

        string getIssue() const { return myIssue; }

        void showWorkTicket() const;

        /*** MUTATORS ***/
        void setWorkTicketNumber(int workTicketNumber);

        void setClientID(string clientID) { myClientID = clientID; }

        void setDate(int day, int month, int year);

        void setIssue(string issue) { myIssue = issue; }

        bool setWorkTicket(int workTicketNumber, string clientID, int day, int month, int year, string issue);


    private:
        int myWorkTicketNumber;
        string myClientID;
        int myDay;
        int myMonth;
        int myYear;
        string myIssue;

};

/*** MAIN ***/
int main () 
{
        // Output an information header
    cout << "=============================" << endl
         << "=== WorkTicket Class Demo ===" << endl
         << "=============================" << endl;

    try
    {
        // DECLARATIONS
        WorkTicket ticketOne(1, "Aaron", 24, 9, 2014, "Printer not accessible from networked computers.");

        ticketOne.showWorkTicket();

    }
    catch(const exception& ex) 
    {
        cerr << ex.what(); // display the exception message.
    }


    // done.
    cout << endl << endl;
    return 0;
}

/*** PARAMETERIZED CONSTRUCTOR ***/
WorkTicket::WorkTicket(int workTicketNumber, string clientID, int day, int month, int year, string issue)
{
    setWorkTicketNumber(workTicketNumber); 
    setClientID(clientID);
    setDate(day, month, year);
    setIssue(issue);
}

/*** ACCESSORS ***/
string WorkTicket::getDate(int myDay, int myMonth, int myYear) const
{
    stringstream dateReturn;

    dateReturn << myDay << "-" << myMonth << "-" << myYear;

    return dateReturn.str();
}

void WorkTicket::showWorkTicket() const
{
        cout << setw(20) << "\nWork Ticket Number: " << myWorkTicketNumber << endl
             << setw(20) << left << "Client ID: " << myClientID << endl
             << setw(20) << left << "Ticket Date: " << myDay << "-" << myMonth << "-" << myYear << endl
             << setw(20) << left << "Issue: " << myIssue << endl;
}

/*** MUTATORS ***/
void WorkTicket::setWorkTicketNumber(int workTicketNumber)
{
    // Local declarations 
    const int MIN_TICKET_NUMBER = 1; // Ace

    if(workTicketNumber < MIN_TICKET_NUMBER)
    {
        // declare a stringstream object
        stringstream strOut; 
        // build a descriptive error string.
        strOut << "\nTicket Number argument: " << workTicketNumber << " is out of range. " << endl
               << "Ticket Number must be greater than or equal to " << MIN_TICKET_NUMBER << ". ";

        // throw an out_of_range exception initialized with
        // the error string
        throw invalid_argument(strOut.str());
    }
    else // otherwise, the rank parameter is fine
    {
        // assign the parameter to the member variable
        myWorkTicketNumber = workTicketNumber;
    }
}

void WorkTicket::setDate(int day, int month, int year)
{
    const int MIN_DAY_MONTH = 1;
    const int MAX_DAY = 31;
    const int MAX_MONTH = 12;
    const int MIN_YEAR = 2000;
    const int MAX_YEAR = 2099;

    stringstream strOut;

    if(day < MIN_DAY_MONTH || day > MAX_DAY)
    {
        // build a descriptive error string.
        strOut << "\nDate argument: " << day << " is out of range. " << endl
               << "Day must be greater than or equal to " << MIN_DAY_MONTH 
               << " and less than or equal to " << MAX_DAY << ". ";

        // throw an out_of_range exception initialized with
        // the error string
        throw invalid_argument(strOut.str());
    }
    else if(month < MIN_DAY_MONTH || month > MAX_MONTH)
    {
        // build a descriptive error string.
        strOut << "\nDate argument: " << month << " is out of range. " << endl
               << "Month must be greater than or equal to " << MIN_DAY_MONTH 
               << " and less than or equal to " << MAX_MONTH << ". ";

        // throw an out_of_range exception initialized with
        // the error string
        throw invalid_argument(strOut.str());
    }
    else if(year < MIN_YEAR || year > MAX_YEAR)
    {
        // declare a stringstream object
        stringstream strOut; 
        // build a descriptive error string.
        strOut << "\nDate argument: " << year << " is out of range. " << endl
               << "Year must be greater than or equal to " << MIN_YEAR 
               << " and less than or equal to " << MAX_YEAR << ". ";

        // throw an out_of_range exception initialized with
        // the error string
        throw invalid_argument(strOut.str());
    }
    else // otherwise, the rank parameter is fine
    {
        // assign the parameter to the member variable
        myDay = day;
        myMonth = month;
        myYear = year;
    }
}   

bool WorkTicket::setWorkTicket(int workTicketNumber, string clientID, int day, int month, int year, string issue)
{


    return true;
}
```

Comment: What is a mutator? Also pass strings by const reference. You can return them by const reference if they return a class member and not a locally constructed string.

Comment: @Neil Mutator/Accessor is the same as Setter/Getter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with just doing:

```
bool WorkTicket::setWorkTicket(int workTicketNumber, string clientID, int day, int month, int year, string issue)
{
    setWorkTicketNumber(workTicketNumber);
    setDate(day, month, year);
    setClientID(clientID);
    setIssue(issue);

    return true;
}
```

You can either let the exceptions propagate or catch them in `setWorkTicket()` and return `false` depending on what you need.

Comment: I'm sorry...I thought I tried doing that and got an error. I guess I had done something else and gotten it wrong? Thank you anyways!

Comment: Pass strings by const reference.